# How could I create realistic structure simulations in blender?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I have this projects in which i need to build a structure that has 2 levels(each level being 1 floor). Each level must hold a golf ball while the structure is shaken. My materials are straws, tape, and a string.

What I want to do is to use Blender since I do not have the materials with me to simulate a structure.

How could I simulate the brittleness of plastic, and the shaking of the plate in which the structure would be upon?

How could I simulate areas where the stiffness is stronger (like where the straws are taped or put in each other)? What about the flexible corners of a straw?